# Automatically convert absolute numbers into to percent values in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am trying to have a chart with percent values instead of the numeric values I'm feeding to it.

This is my chart:
[image]

Is there an option to automatically convert the numbers in the bar chart to percentages? (In the example, there is a range from 0 to 50,000, and I want that to be converted from 0% to 100%).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can have y axis in percentage 0,10,20 .... 100%
You must have total num , in this case total = 50000;

**Now get the data and calculate % as = data/total * 100**
 and plot it on graph. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I know that I can get data and calculate I asked there is an option for do this automatically.

Comment: if you are using d3 charts then there are options when it does it.

Comment: in echarts there are a lots of option for do any thing that we want but I can't find any option for convert into percentage, maybe it doesn't have this option

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is `(100/maxValue) * value`.

```js
var max = document.getElementById("max");
var offset = document.getElementById("offset");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var c = document.getElementById("c").getContext("2d");


function getPercentage() {
  var all = parseInt(max.value);
  var off = parseInt(offset.value);
  output.innerHTML = ((100 / all) * off) + "%";

  c.fillStyle="#eee";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, c.canvas.width, c.canvas.height);
  c.fillStyle="red";
  c.fillRect(25, c.canvas.height, 50, 0 - ((1 / all) * off) * c.canvas.height)
}

max.onchange = getPercentage;
max.onkeyup = getPercentage;
offset.onchange = getPercentage;
offset.onkeyup = getPercentage;

getPercentage()
```

```html
<label>Max: <input type="number" value="100" id="max"/></label><br>
<label>Offset: <input type="number" value="90" id="offset"/></label>
<p id="output"></p>
<canvas id="c" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```